# How to level shift an analog signal?

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, circuit-analysis, level-translation

I have a sinusoidal input signal (with a swing of 100mV roughly) centered around 100mV (DC). This signal needs to be input to a CMOS inverter. For this I need to level shift my signal around the inverter's threshold voltage. 
I need a transistor level schematic that does just that: level shift my sinus input signal around the inverter's threshold, preferably with some form of feedback to deal with threshold voltage variations of the CMOS inverter (i.e. a circuit that shifts the signal around the inverter's threshold, even if that threshold voltage value changes).

Is this possible ?
Any ideas as to how this could be done ?

Comment: You want to turn the sine into a square wave using the inverter? If so then use a comparator circuit.

Comment: What kind of inverter are you using? Is it a CMOS gate or an op-amp or what?

Comment: @Dwayne Reid - The inverter is a simple CMOS gate.

@ Andy - It's more or less what I'm trying to build, but either case, I first need to center my input signal around the threshold voltage of inverter or the compactor, I think; no ?

Comment: The point of a comparator (like an LM339) is that you can put the switching threshold anywhere in the operational range and get a digital output signal. So if your signal swings around 100mv, put your threshold at 100mv (use resistor divider to create this reference) and the output will swing digital levels suitable to connect to any standard digital device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old technique that I saw many years ago that looks like it is applicable to your situation.

By the looks of things, you are using a linear CMOS inverter as an amplifier.  I say "linear" as opposed to Schmitt Trigger.  Note that these should be un-buffered inverters such as CD4069UB.  The "UB" suffix indicates un-buffered.

The issue is that you need to bias your input signal right in the center of the linear region of the inverter.  This voltage is usually different for inverters from different manufacturers and is often different for inverters even from the same manufacturer.

There *is* a simple solution.  Simply use one inverter from that package to set that bias point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffEvy5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top section is a classic linear amplifier using an un-buffered CMOS inverter.  Notice how the feedback sets the bias point for the inverter right in the middle of the linear region.

We use the same principle to generate a bias point for the inverter sections that you want to use as comparitors.  Note that they aren't really comparitors but they function much the same way - you feed your signal into an amplifier running open-loop (no feedback) so as to square up the signal.

The bottom inverter simply has its' input tied to its' output.  This forces the output to be centered in the middle of the linear region.  Note that this is a relatively-low impedance node.

You then take that voltage and use it to bias the inputs of the comparitor stages to that same voltage.

This works so well because all of the inverter stages in any given package are very closely matched.

A standard inverter package has 6 inverters.  You would use one inverter from each package to generate the bias voltage for the remaining 5 inverters in that package.  You should NOT use that voltage to set the bias for inverters in a different package because the bias point might be different.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a simple blocking capacitor with a variable resistor to 'add back' a DC level.

The capacitor C1 removes the DC level of the signal and passes only the AC (sinusoid) to the wiper of VR1 forming a high pass filter. By varying the wiper position you can set the new DC level between O and +V. Values should be chosen to be appropriate to signal frequency.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I considered this option, but it only enables me to center my signal around a certain DC level that is not necessarily the threshold voltage of my inverter.
What if in 1 circuit, this threshold is equal to say 0.4V, and on another, 0.5 V: I would need to manually and tediously adjust the resistor value for each individual circuit ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways I can think of approaching that problem:

1) Is the input signal always the same amplitude and always present?  Does it matter if the output of the inverter oscillates at a low frequency with no-signal present?

If so a very easy way is to use a Schmidt trigger inverter (e.g. 74HC14) couple the input signal with a capacitor and have a feedback resistor from the output of the inverter back to its input - it will then automatically center the offset to the threshold level with no adjustment.

2) For something a bit more general first amplify the 100mV signal to something like 1-2V then AC couple it to the schmidt trigger with a fixed bias.  With the larger signal voltage it won't matter if the threshold voltage of the inverter changes unit to unit.  For even better accuracy use a comparator instead of an inverter.

kevin